# Steps to Host OWIN KATANA Access Token ASP.NET Web Api application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, token, owin, katana

We have developed sample application which has OWIN KATANA Token based authentication and authorization is implemented in ASP.NET webapi. We wanted to host it in IIS. With IIS express its working with all endpoints and Token got generated. However when hosted in IIS, with Post request to get the Token , it says "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error".

Any thoughts on this, that should be handled to make it work with IIS.

Comment: Just to add already Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb is being referred in the application.

Comment: Please ignore the post

Comment: What is the actual error? Please read this to enable detailed error information: http://chuchuva.com/pavel/2010/08/how-to-enable-detailed-error-information-for-iis-and-asp-net/

Answer (score 0):

There is no required to do any special configuration

Please check your database **connection** string as well as **Web.config** file.